# Swift - Reach Personal Documents

Tags: ios, swift

I research some topics about IOS personal data protection for App presentation. I can reach the document directory and upload all files from App to Server( or can collect all contact list). Is this avaliable at Photo Gallery?.

Comment: are you asking that from app "is it possible to access photo library ?"

Comment: definitely yes. Access and Pull whole library without any 'pick' functions.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, pulling up photos from photolibrary using Photos.

Below is the example:

```
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
//Array of PHAsset type for storing photos
var images = [PHAsset]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    getImages()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func getImages() {
    let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: nil)
    assets.enumerateObjects({ (object, count, stop) in
        // self.cameraAssets.add(object)
        self.images.append(object)
    })

    //In order to get latest image first, we just reverse the array
    self.images.reverse()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    let imageAsset = self.images[indexPath.row]
    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: imageAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 120.0, height: 120.0), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil) { (result, _) in
        cell?.imageView?.image = result
    }
    return cell!
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }
    }
```

Comment: I ask to pull in background not any picking at anywhere.

Comment: @AliIhsanURAL I have updated my answer please check now

Comment: It works @Mridul . But with this theory all apps can collect our library. Is there any protection from apple for this ?